# findById returning a list of documents instead of a single result

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, postman

I'm trying to get an item object via its object Id from mongodb, but when i tried to call that route in postman it gives me a list of every single object in the database (total of 4 objects) instead of the expected one object.

Here's the function i created for getting one object from the database

```
getEvent : function(id,callback)
{
   EventModel.findById(id,callback);
},
```

And Below is my routes

```
router.get('/events/:id',function(req,res)
{
    var id = req.params.id;
    db.getEvent(id,function(err,event)
    {
        if(err)
        {
            console.log("Error processing data");
        }
        else{
            console.log("get one event is called");
            res.send(event)`enter code here`;
        }
    })
});
```

And Finally Below is the result

[Postman Test Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLhvm.png)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is correct, the way you are making request is wrong

Your Format :

```
http://localhost:3000/events?id=someid
```

`id = someID` in the URL represents a `GET` query parameter.

If you are using wildcard parameters like `:id` in the route, then the request URL should be :

```
http://localhost:3000/events/someid
```

`someid` will now be present in `req.params.id`

You are getting all the objects is because the variable `id` is `undefined` in your case, undefined parameters are omitted by default. So it is same as calling : 
`EventModel.findById({}, callback)`

Thanks

Comment: @dave.. thats exactly where the problem is. Or if you don't wanna change your route structure, just change ```var id = req.params.id;``` with ```var id = req.query.id;```

Comment: @Narasimha Prasanna HN I tried your answer and it worked, tks for the help :)

Comment: http://localhost:3000/events?id=someid , oh by the way this url was generated by postman when i went to the params tab and input id in the key column and the itemid in the value column

Answer (score 1):

You can try calling **Model.findOne()** instead of **Model.findById**

```
EventModel.findOne({id}, callback)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping ;) Your method worked for me as well